# PHP session vars not unique across browsers

Tags: php, session

I'm developing a website that uses $_SESSION variables in PHP to determine if a user is logged in. On my one server (DEV server) the $_SESSION variables work as expected and I can determine if a user is logged in. I can even determine which user is logged in and the code works fine.

**The problem:**
When I move the exact same code over to my production or "live" server the different $_SESSION variables get mixed up. In the live environment, once a user is logged in, they stay logged in and I can even access that user's session from a different computer on a different network that has never accessed the site.

Both servers use the same Linux OS, same PHP version same everything. (They're two separate identical servers, one for dev and one for production).

Any idea why the one server would work fine and the other one is "broken"?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Login code:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    $user_id = $_REQUEST["user_id"];

    if (user_login())
    {
        $_SESSION["UserLoggedIN"] = $user_id;
    }

    function user_login()
    {

        $sql = "SELECT password FROM db.users WHERE user_id = '". $user_id ."';";
        $result = execute_get_sql($sql)['st_password'];

        if (strcmp($res, $_REQUEST["password"]) == 0)
        {
          return true;
        }

        display_error(2);
        return false; 
    }
?>
```

Log out code:

```
<?php

session_destroy();

?>
```

Code to check if user is logged in on other pages:

```
<?php

if (empty($_SESSION["UserLoggedIN"]))
{
    //do log out...
}

echo $_SESSION["UserLoggedIN"];

?>
```

Comment: Put in your question a minimum code that represents the problem.

Comment: Can you provide the code of user_login() ?

Comment: I think problem is about caching. Do you use cache in production server?

Comment: According to my the phpinfo(); both servers' caching is off